# what is the result of Z+ in ps command?

Tags: unix, process, posix

i made a zombie process with this code :

`pid_t child;
cout<<getpid();

child=fork();

if (child>0)
    sleep(60);
else
    exit(0);`

and i'm using this command :

ps -e -o pid,ppid,stat,command

it's okey , but i expect see Z in front of my process(stat) but it's Z+ , what thats mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page for ps, more specifically the process state codes:

```
Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
+    is in the foreground process group.
```

When the shell executes your code, it changes your program to a separate foreground process group. Every child of your code is in the same foreground process group as the original program, so even once the parent exits, the child is still in the foreground process group which is why you see the +.